# Calling main activity from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android

While developing an alarm based application, i have stuck in a scenario.

When my alarm is fired, i can receive the event in BroadCastReceiver::onReceive().
Within this function, i want to notify/call a function, which is located on MainActivity.

How to achieve the same??

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move the function to it's own class and call it from both your Activity AND your Receiver?

Comment: When the alarm is invoked , i want to reset all alarms , and create new alarms depending on the present system time.

Comment: Sounds like you're doing something very similar to something I'm working on at the moment which uses Alarms.

I never set more than one alarm at a time, instead my alarmsetting code always decides what the next alarm time will be and sets just one alarm..  when it goes off, in the broadcast receiver after its created a notification it then finds the next time an alarm should go off and sets a new alarm..

This way I'm always only working with ONE pending intent making it much easier to cancel/set

Answer (score 0):

Create the BroadcastReceiver dinamically:

in your BroadcastReceiver class define member:

```
YourMainActivity yourMain = null;
```

and method:

```
setMainActivityHandler(YourMainActivity main){
yourMain = main;
}
```

from your MainActivity do:

```
private YourBroadcastReceiverClassName yourBR = null;
yourBR = new YourBroadcastReceiverClassName();
        yourBR.setMainActivityHandler(this);
        IntentFilter callInterceptorIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.ANY_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(callInterceptor,  callInterceptorIntentFilter);
```

finally, when yourBR.onReceive is fired you can call:

```
yourMain.methodOfMainActivity();
```